# Issue in open a new window at the time of loading a page

Tags: javascript, tapestry

I am developing web application for smart phones using tapestry. I have an issue, when open a new window at the time of page loading, but it didn't open.

I am using following code to achieve that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
javascript:OpenWindow('${pname}',340,360);
</script>
```

Sample.js:

```
function OpenWindow(AppName,ww,hh) { 
window.open("layout/play/"+AppName.toLowerCase()+".html","a"+AppName+"Window","width="+ww+",height="+hh+",menubar=no,locationbar=no,resizable=yes,status=no,scrollbars=no");
}
```

Please any one help me.

Comment: Use <body onload="OpenWindow('${pname}',340,360);">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't do this

```
javascript:OpenWindow('${pname}',340,360);
```

do this instead

```
window.onload = function(){

      OpenWindow('${pname}',340,360);              
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's working in desktop browser but not in iphone.

Comment: are you checking in safari browser

Comment: Its working in safari browser when I off block pop up window option in safari settings. If I on block pop up window option its not open in a new window. So I am depend on the safari browser pop up window setting.                                                            How can I open a new window without depend on the block pop window settings in safari browser.